# Как работает программа (количество перестановок)

Tags: c, алгоритм, рекурсия

переделал рекурсивную программу с интернета с++ на си, заменил операторы и так далее.
Она выводит все перестановки числа , но я все не могу понять как))

```
int X[100];
int n;
void Swap(int a, int b)
{
    int t = X[a];
    X[a] = X[b];
    X[b] = t;
}
void Generate(int k)
{
    if (k == n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            printf("%d ",X[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = k; j<n; j++)
        {
            Swap(k, j);
            Generate(k + 1);
            Swap(k, j);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("N=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        X[i] = i + 1;
    Generate(0);
    getch();
}
```

Я понял, что вводится число (допустим 3 и мы высчитываем все перестановки от 1 до 3)
Далее заполняется массив со всеми элементами будущей перестановки
после чего вызывается функция Generate(почему от нуля?)
и для чего нам менять местами элементы в функции Swap.
в общем туго совсем не понимаю, прошу помощи.

Comment: Попробуйте написать свою

Answer (score 1):

Да тут все просто. Мы поочередно ка k-е место ставим все цифры по очереди, и генерируем 
все перестановки оставшихся цифр. Для ваших трех чисел это выглядит так.

Сначала на первом месте 1, и мы рекурсивно генерируем все перестановки из 2, 3. Для этого на второе место ставим поочередно 2 и 3, и генерируем все перестановки из одного третьего элемента. Потом возврат на предыдущий уровень, вместо 1 ставится 2, и опять рекурсивно генерируются перестановки для оставшихся двух цифр.

По сути - если смотреть с конца - то все перестановки для одного элемента получаются тривиальным образом. А далее - для N элементов мы поочередно на первое место ставим все элементы по очереди и генерируем все перестановки для N-1 элемента.

Достаточно понятно или нужно продолжить? :)